# Enforcing Strong Password with PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, passwords

I am trying to check, if a user has created a password that contains symbols (including +,-,= signs) OR/AND numbers.
How can I do that?

```
function check_password($str)
{

   if (!preg_match ("/[&@<>%\*\,\^!#$%().]/i", $str))

    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_password', 'Your password should contain a number,letter,and special characters"');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you provide the answer with your question?

Comment: I personally, I *hate* sites that force me to have some weird-ass special character in my password. Because the only effect that has on me is that I tend to forget it, and need to write it down, creating a security hole in the process - a hole larger than a dictionary attack will ever be if you do *some* rate limiting on login attempts.

Comment: What if I want to use an `_`? `<cry />`

Comment: You are searching a solution for a non-problem. This code creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: @Pekka Add to that inconsistent "strong passowrd" policies across sites. My password generation scheme fails at this site because I'm not allowed to use spaces, or at that site because it wants me to use special chars *except* the ones I happen to use...

Comment: i like the js that tells the user the password is weak or strong, then its there call if they still want to use it, the only thing i force is a password length

Answer (score 7):

My suggestion for password strength checking is to break each requirement you have into separate regexs, particularly:

```
   $regexs = array(
                 '/[0-9]+/',  // Numbers
                 '/[a-z]+/',  // Lower Case Letters
                 '/[A-Z]+/',  // Upper Case Letters
                 '/[+-=]+/',  // Your list of allowable symbols.
   );
```

Initialize a counter to 0.  For each regex, test to see if it matches.  If it does, increase the counter by 1.  Then return true if counter is greater than 3 (or 4 if you want them to have a really really strong password), otherwise return false.

I think this would be much more maintainable for you in the long run if your requirements ever change.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to list all those characters. Anything that is not a number or a letter is a special character (or space):

```
(?:[^0-9A-z]|[0-9])
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking in a different direction. If you are to impose a restriction, just require it to be longer. As has been pointed out, using symbols will most likely cause the user to forget the password and never come back to your site. For maximum security post the following comic on the registration page: http://xkcd.com/936/